# Why is my .htaccess code slowing down my site?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a quick question about .htaccess. Why does my site load faster when using this URL:

http://www.phaidi.com/network/index.php?p=home&s=chaumyvn

Than by going straight to the chaumy.vn domain?

I think it has something to do with my .htaccess, but I have not been able to fix it. See my .htaccess file below:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} chaumy.vn
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !network/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ /network/index.php?p=$1&s=chaumyvn [R=301] 

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: mod_rewrite has some overhead, and you are redirecting the browser to phaidi.com, which has an additional request involved on another domain (which will involve a second DNS lookup). How big is the difference? Also, the redirect has an empty GET var for p which could make a difference in your PHP code?

Comment: I am talking about the site loading 3x slower, not just a little bit. And I was concerned about the empty GET var as well, but it didn't slow it down though. I think there might be something with the folder rewrite cond that could be done better?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fix all the slowness, but a quick remark.

You are only excluding the network folder from the rewrite rule, however what about your static files (/css/, favicon etc.) They will all be rewriting to your network/index.php file as well.

Besides that for production environments (especially on high-traffic websites) I've heard it's better to put the 'htaccess' information straight into the apache/virtualhost configuration, as it saves Apache from having to scan for the htaccess and parse is for every request. But it shouldn't save 'that much' in this situation.

Comment: It seems like the current redirect sends me to "http://chaumy.vn/network/index.php?p=&s=chaumyvn" when it should send me to "http://www.phaidi.com/network/index.php?p=&s=chaumyvn". I don't really get it.

Comment: Your .htaccess doesn't say that it should change "hostnames" as well, maybe you are looking for a 301 redirect. Quick example I found on the googles for you: http://www.strangework.com/2008/06/30/how-to-301-redirect-from-one-domain-to-another-using-mod_rewrite/